# Manufacting quality issues medication dispensed by UK pharmacy

Tags: mediation, import

UK consumer collects medication from a UK pharmacy. Medication has obvious manufacturing quality issues identified before leaving the pharmacy.

Does the pharmacy has the obligation to report the quality issue to their supplier; or does the consumer has to deal directly with the manufacturer regarding the medication quality issues?

What would be the correct procedure in this case?

Comment: I doubt this is all relevant, but just in case: was this prescribed or over the counter medicine? If prescribed, was it an NHS prescription - and did you pay for it - or a private prescription? Is there something wrong with the medicine, or was it just e.g. a damaged box or blister pack (but didn't expose the pills). Did you get replacement good quality medicine from the pharmacy or did they refuse? Was it a chain pharmacy or an independent one?

Comment: NHS prescription. Not private. Sent directly to the pharmacy from the GP. Repeat medication, no issues for past 5 months. 4 bottles of prescribed oral medication (liquid form in a glass bottle) per month. Last 2 out of 4 bottles liquid is off inside. But expiration is 06/2024. Packaging is not damaged. The pharmacy did not replace the off medication. So I have no medication. 
Pharmacy told me they cannot report medicine being off to their supplier. They claim I have to contact the manufacturer. But only contact details in packaging are for a UK warehouse (medication from Japan manufacturer).

Comment: :-( That sounds ridiculous and wrong to me, but I can't give you a legal answer sorry. I'd try my GP, show them the off medicine and see if I could get another prescription to make up. I can see no reason you'd be expected to go direct to the manufacturer: if you bought it from a shop and it's faulty the shop would have to refund or replace it. But maybe the situation is a bit murky with prescriptions.

Comment: [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/consumer-protection-rights) suggests Citizens Advice Bureau for disputes over faulty goods. [Here's their relevant page](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/somethings-gone-wrong-with-a-purchase/return-faulty-goods/).

Comment: Agreed. That's what I thought while I was in the pharmacy being told such ridiculous suggestion. But, last thing I want is to start an argument with the only pharmacy that agreed five months ago to order this medication. It's imported so other pharmacies I tried didn't even know the medication and as soon as I explained is imported they refused to order it. I called my GP for advice and they said the pharmacy should have reported the quality issues to their supplier and order a replacement. Because they don't want to do any of this, my GP suggested to send my prescription to another pharmacy.

Comment: But I tried 20+ so far including Boots pharmacy without luck. It's all very strange and difficult for no good reason. Pharmacies are a public service to a point. Medication is not covered by the buying consumers law. As it is a dispenser not a seller of medication. Or that's what I gathered from another thread on this platform. Anyway, I'm screwed. I literally can't eat without the medication. They will just send me to hospital and let me die slowly. They don't care, not the GP, not the pharmacy not the health system in this country.